# Why does my ec2 instance appear empty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I `ssh` into my ec2 instance and run `ls -a` I see:

```
..  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  .ssh  .viminfo
```

and yet when I open the url associated with the instance, I see the standard welcome page, so it appears there must be an `index.html` located in the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default document root on an EC2 instance is:

```
/var/www/html
```

You should see the standard Amazon EC2 `index.html` file in there.

Comment: Thanks, `/var/www/html` exists, but it appears to be empty.

Comment: @RosePerrone - Check in '/var/www'

Answer (score 0):

When I created a flask app, I found its code in `/opt/python/bundle/3/app/templates`. Where I'm pretty sure `3` represents the i'th `git aws.push` I've run.